# Need help understanding したところで/ところで in this context

Tags: parsing, set-phrases, japanese-to-english, understanding

So in this manga (月が導く異世界道中) there are these 2 sisters where the older one made some bad decisions about borrowing money from the wrong kind of people. After being rescued the younger sister says to her:

おねえちゃんお金はちゃんとしたところで借りたの?

I have trouble understanding this. When looking up "..したところで" I find translations that make it mean "even if", "even when" or "even though".
On my own I come up with these 2 possible translation(s)

1. Even though you used the money well, did you return it?
2. About the money - after using it well, did you return it?

As the thugs are vanquished there is IMO no loan giver that could receive the remaining money.

Thanks a lot!

(My question might be connected to [ところで as ところ + で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97315/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d%e3%81%a7-as-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d-%e3%81%a7)
or [What's the difference between としたところで and　にしたところで and how to use it in a "positive" way](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83998/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d%e3%81%a7-and-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d%e3%81%a7-and-how-to-use-it-in-a-positi))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ところ simply means "place." ちゃんとしたところ, therefore, means a proper place (or lender). It has nothing to do with the 〜したところで that you looked up.

Comment: Now I get it. In my translation above the 借りた at the sentence end doesn't make any sense after all! Now it does :) Thank you!